# How do I make the column type date I want to insert in sql

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to insert the date format into sql

How can I do this?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Server-1;Initial Catalog=Eczane;Integrated Security=True");
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TBL_Musteri (MUSTERI_TC,MUSTERI_AD,MUSTERI_SOYADI,MUSTERI_DOGUM_TARIHI,MUSTERI_CINSIYET,MUSTERI_TELEFON,MUSTERI_ADRES,MUSTERI_IL,MUSTERI_ILCE,MUSTERI_EKLEYEN_ADMIN) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox9.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "')", conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Erorr!");
            }
        }
```

Comment: textbox9 operation

Comment: take care this is source of sql injection issue Yunus kardeş

Comment: Why do you want to change sql date format?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what i want

Comment: You should see... http://stackoverflow.com/a/5721979/2026740

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Parameters` collection on `cmd` object.

You can specify the type and the conversion will be done for you. Also it prevents your code from being exposed to SQL injection.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TBL_Musteri (MUSTERI_TC,MUSTERI_AD,MUSTERI_SOYADI,MUSTERI_DOGUM_TARIHI,
MUSTERI_CINSIYET,MUSTERI_TELEFON,MUSTERI_ADRES,MUSTERI_IL,MUSTERI_ILCE,MUSTERI_EKLEYEN_ADMIN) 
VALUES (@param1,@param2,@param3,@param4,@param5,
@param6,@param7,@param8,@param9,@param10)", conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@param1"] = textBox1.Text;
...
cmd.Parameters.Add("@param4", SqlDbType.Date;
cmd.Parametes["@param4"] = textBox9.Text;
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest